# Is there a way to make these 2 divs inline

Tags: html, css

I have used `display:inline-block` but its not working
Is there a way to make orange and green inline?

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mih3r)**

Comment: I am not seeing any orange div, only green i can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` for `.s`

```
.s{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: When added this,a white space square came in between green and orange div.

Comment: remove margin-left for `.b `

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `white-space: nowrap;` to your parent div `.s`

Answer (score 0):

```
.a {
width: 50%;
margin-left: 0;
background-color: rgb(49, 219, 126);
height: 400px;
display: inline-block;
}

.b {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(250, 150, 0);
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.s{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

The problem is that there's no available width on the surrounding container.

**UPDATE**

Since you want it scrollable you can use overflow like this:

```
.s{
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: When added this,a white space square came in between green and orange div.

Comment: I don't see any white space can you make sure you're using the same css.

Comment: @Cap-7 Updated my answer based on your comment to pedram's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.s[_ngcontent-tpw-c0] {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}


.a[_ngcontent-tpw-c0] {
    background-color: rgb(49, 219, 126);
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
}
.b[_ngcontent-tpw-c0] {
    background-color: rgb(250, 150, 0);
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: width cannot be changed. As i want the green content to be in the second screen,horizontally

Comment: Can you provide and explanation of each class.